# HTML characters

Tags: html, character

Whenever I do type something like this in HTML:

```
<h1>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h1>
```

I don't get a header that has the shrugging emoticon. Instead, I see this:

Â¯_(ãƒ„)_/Â¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various characters have special meanings in html. So that's why your code doesn't give you what you wanted. For example the `\` character escapes the following character.
A good reference to many of these codes can be found [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)!
Or just search html character codes on google!

and here is the code that solves your problem:
 
    `<h1>&#175;&#92;&#95;(&#12484;)&#95;&#47;&#175;</h1>`